# Joomla generating class "icon-*" but don't load the graphics

Tags: icon

The email/print icons on an article shows up as text instead of graphics (the cog is an "8", e-mail shows as "ME-mail" or the print icon as a square "[]Print"). Obviously some font is not loading correctly.

How can I find out what's wrong?

Running Joomla 3.6.2 with Joostrap Ripped template.

Comment: These icons should be coming from the IcoMoon fontset. Can you inspect the element (Firebug, Chrome Dev tools, etc) and see if this is being overridden by anything?

Comment: What do you mean by "overridden"? If I "inspect" the `<span class="icon-cog">` there is no `font-family=icomoon` specified at all. (Looking at computed, which should show all, right?

Comment: Hmm, well this template is $49 which covers forum support, so I'd suggest posting on their forum as it's their issue. it's very hard to tell without seeing a live preview of the site (and being logged in). They appear to use Font Awesome so perhaps they haven't mapped the CSS classes correctly

Comment: I have posted but with no response as of now. And I was hoping to learn something for myself over here. BTW, page example is http://events.responsive.se/events/index.php/devlin2016/presentationerna/164-varje-team-behoever-minst-en-testare-johan-jonasson

Comment: The icons are showing perfectly fine for me. Please try clearing your Joomla and browser cache

Comment: Just fixed it. Actually with some belated answer on Joostrap forum. I'll post answer in a minute. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template had neither mapped the CSS classes for icons correctly nor included the Icomoon font CSS.

Through the support of Joostrap I added the following to the beginning of `template/<name>/index.php`:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl.'/media/jui/css/icomoon.css');
```

So that the beginning of it reads:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joostrap.Template
 * @subpackage  Joostrap v3.1.6
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Joostrap. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
require_once __DIR__ . '/functions/tpl-init.php';

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl.'/media/jui/css/icomoon.css');

?>
```

You can also read about this in the [Joomla docs](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Joomla_Standard_Icomoon_Fonts), which says exactly this:

```
To include the Icomoon fonts in your template you will have to add the css
stylesheet (/media/jui/css/icomoon.css) or include it in your .less file
when you generate the .css stylesheet(s).

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl.'/media/jui/css/icomoon.css');
```